# Floating objects in a physically correct way

Tags: fluid-simulation

How can I float an object in a fluid? 
For example I have a fluid container and a ball placed in it. Then filling the container through a pipe with fluid and I want the ball to float based on its size and weight.
Is there a way to achieve this in 2.79b or in 2.80?

Comment: It's not possible with Fluid (elbeem) simulation. There is a way I have tried a long time ago with Molecular add-on. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/TKhjh

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded it and see how that works. It seems to be for 2.7xx versions only, does not work with 2.80.

Comment: Yeah, it's heavily outdated. Sadly Pyroevil is not working on it for a long time, and nobody else picked this amazing idea further. Maybe with everything node system and physics overhaul we will see something similar in 2.8x. Maybe.

Comment: I have seen this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9TViIgm8Yc, YouTube video where this guy is developing a FLIP system, not the FLIP commercial plugin, but practically want to do the same as that one. Currently this new system cannot deal with viscosity. Apparently when this new fluid system will be ready they want to replace the current elbeem with that one. Not sure when that will see the day of light.